# FileNotFoundException: for properties file in Spring Boot application deployed in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a Spring Boot application, which uses some parameters from a properties file located in src/main/config. I need to run this app on different environments: DEV, SIT, PROD, etc. and I need to change the properties from that file every time.

I have this file in the classpath, in src/main/config and also in the tomcat folder, in instance-config. When I deploy the app on Tomcat, I need it to use the configs from the file located in the tomcat folder.

I have a problem, though: it cannot find my properties file.

I tried to create some profiles in order to use that properties file from the classpath(src/main/config) only on "dev", but I cannot finish the build because it gives me error: " Failed to parse configuration class [com.db.wmdl.config.TestConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [wmdl_options_app.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist"

I have this profiles section in pom:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/config</directory>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>tomcat</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

This is the class which contains a reference to the properties file:

```
@SpringBootApplication( scanBasePackages = {"com.db.wmdl.glue2g.*","com.db.wmdl.fo.service","com.db.wmdl.fo.persistence", "com.db.wmdl.fo.serversync"})
@PropertySource("classpath:wmdl_options_app.properties")
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException {
        LoggerContext context = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        context.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("log4j-dl-fo-config.xml").getURI());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

How can I make my application work and read the properties from the instance-config folder ?

Comment: Just double verify if the packaged build contains the required file in the classpath.

Comment: Since this is a new Boot application, what is your reason for using `war` and an external Tomcat instead of a self-running application?

Comment: because I have to deploy it in prod, for example and we use a platform where I need to put a war

Comment: this is why I need the app to look for the properties in the tomcat instance-config folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these to tomcat profile as well if you are using tomcat profile to run.

```
<build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/config</directory>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
```

Also, by default, the tomcat profile is active. You need to specifically activate dev profile.

Comment: it worked, I do not longer have that error, but it gets the properties from the src/main/config. Is there any way I can make it, when deployed, use the file from the tomcat folder?

Comment: After the build process, the war application put them into the classpath directory. If you are doubtful, then you can explore the war file and see how classes and resources are organised into a single build. To read the properties from the Tomcat folder, I would suggest to add the properties in env variable.